# SQL Inner join many to many multi part identifier not bound

Tags: sql, inner-join

```
select Course.CourseName as course_coursename
    ,Instructor.Name as instructor_instructorname 
from Course  
    inner join CourseInstructor as CI 
        on Instructor.InstructorID=CourseInstructor.InstructorID
        and Course.CourseID = CourseInstructor.CourseID
```

This is a query I made to inner join many to many table.  I have course and instructor table and join table which includes the course and instructorid.

I want to inner join the tables to display the courses taught by each instructor but getting an error:

> `multipart identifier could not be bound`

.. for instructor.name, instructor.insturctorid, courseinstructor.instructorid and courseinstructor.courseid.

Comment: When asking SQL questions, both sample input and expected outcome as tables are required, furthermore the structure of all affected tables must be clear. Please read and follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

The error basically states that you are referencing a table called Instructor that the query cannot find in the query itself. Your `SELLECT` does reference a table called `Instructor`, but the `CourseInstructor` table is subsequently aliased as `CI`:

```
inner join CourseInstructor as CI
```

Change that to

```
inner join CourseInstructor as Instructor
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use everywhere in the `SELECT`  and in the `ON` clause the same table names or aliases that are defined in  the `FROM` clause

So your query mus look like this

```
select Course.CourseName as course_coursename
,Instructor.Name as 
instructor_instructorname 
from Course  inner join 
CourseInstructor as Instructor on Course.InstructorID = Instructor.InstructorID
AND Course.CourseID = Instructor.CourseID
```